# Displaying menu in theme

Tags: 7, theming

How do I render a menu in a theme? Is there an easy way to do this?

I would prefer just a line of code that calls all the menu items in for a custom menu.

Say for example I had a menu named "brands"

How would I put that on my page--front.tpl.php?

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this out of one my themes:

```
<div class="menu">
    <?php
        print theme(
            "links",
            array(
                "links" => menu_navigation_links("MENU-NAME"),
                "attributes" => array(
                    "class" => array(
                        "links",
                        "menu-links"
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    ?>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use [Menu Block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module and assign a menu block to a region, thus removing all of the ugly code from above from your theme file.

Comment: Do either of these solutions print out the title of the menu?

Comment: Menu Block might, theme function wouldn't